# Чем class отличается от struct?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Чем `class` отличается от `struct`? Когда использовать одно, а когда другое?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Отличия

В С++ *классом* называются типы объявленные с помощью `class`, `struct` или `union`.

Это означает что в С++ есть только *классы*, и все правила для `class` и `struct` одинаковы, за исключением случаев где отличия указаны явно.

Отличий `class` от `struct` всего два

> *Member access control [class.access]*
>
> Члены класса, определенного с помощью ключевого слова `class`, по умолчанию являются `private`. Члены класса, определенного с помощью ключевого слова `struct` или `union`, по умолчанию являются `public`.
>
> *Accessibility of base classes and base class members [class.access.base]*
>
> При отсутствии спецификатора доступа (т.е. private/protected/public) у базового класса, базовый класс будет `public` если класс определен с помощью `struct` и `private` если класс определен с помощью `class`.

(Хотя `union` и является классом, он имеет много других отличий от `class` и `struct`, что выходит за рамки этого вопроса.)

#### Использование

Есть популярное мнение, что для "<strike>расово</strike> правильных ООП классов" надо использовать только `class`, а для структур данных - только `struct`, и еще у `struct` не должно быть методов. Это не более чем вкусовщина, и подобные вещи должны быть закреплены в руководствах по стилю кодирования, как например это сделано в [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Structs_vs._Classes).

В коротких примерах кода, предпочтительнее использовать `struct`, и не использовать private/public, если они не относятся к сути проблемы.

Comment: Про union зря упомянули, эта конструкция все же имеет отличия.

Comment: Создается ложное впечатление, что struct и union - одно и тоже. Лучше либо дополнить про union, либо убрать его из ответа.