# Преобразование X* в Y* существует, но недоступно

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Начал изучать паттерны проектирования и заглох на первой главе книги. Книга написана для джавистов, но я решил перевести код на C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// interfaces
class FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0;
};

class QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack() = 0;
};

// Flying
class FlyWithWings
        : FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly()
    {
        cout << "I'm flying" << endl;
    }
};

class FlyNoWay
        : FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly()
    {
        cout << "I can't fly" << endl;
    }
};

// Quacking
class Quack
        : QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack()
    {
        cout << "Quack!" << endl;
    }
};

class MuteQuack
        : QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack()
    {
        cout << "Silence..." << endl;
    }
};

class Squeak
        : QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack()
    {
        cout << "Squeak!" << endl;
    }
};

class Duck
{
public:
    FlyBehavior     *flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior   *quackBehavior;

    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual void performFly()
    {
        flyBehavior->fly();
    }
    virtual void performQuack()
    {
        quackBehavior->quack();
    }
    void swim()
    {
        cout << "All ducks float" << endl;
    }

};


class MallardDuck
        : Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
    {
        flyBehavior     = new FlyWithWings();
        quackBehavior   = new Quack();
    }

    virtual void display()
    {
        cout << "Typical mallard duck" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Duck *pMallard  = new MallardDuck();
    pMallard->performFly();
    pMallard->performQuack();

    return 0;
}
```

Не совсем понимаю, почему нельзя перевести из `FlyBehavior*` в `FlyWithWings*`.
Знаю, что из интерфейса нельзя создать объект, но я преобразовываю в объект как бы определенного класса.

Ошибки компиляции:

> \main.cpp:97: ошибка: C2243: приведение типов: преобразование
>   "FlyWithWings *" в "FlyBehavior *" существует, но недоступно
>
> \main.cpp:98: ошибка: C2243: приведение типов: преобразование "Quack
>   *" в "QuackBehavior *" существует, но недоступно
>
> \main.cpp:110: ошибка: C2243: приведение типов: преобразование "MallardDuck *" в
>    "Duck *" существует, но недоступно

Comment: `class Quack : public QuackBehavior`. Для такого нужно публичное наследование

Comment: @andy.37 , действительно, работает. Я думал, что по умолчанию идет наследование модификатором public. Впредь буду внимательнее. Спасибо

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420635/176217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже замечено в комментарии к вопросу, для преобразования типов требуется публичное наследование.

Запись вида:

```
class D : B
```

эквивалентна

```
class D : private B
```

Чтобы обеспечить возможность приведения типов нужно указать публичное наследование:

```
class D : public B
```

Если бы вместо `class` использовалось `struct`, то наследование по умолчанию было бы `public` и указанная проблема не возникла.